# Grep not working with anchor tags

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I'm trying to find every word in `/usr/dict/words` whose characters match those of my name. I thought this would work:

```
cat /usr/dict/words | grep "^[mason]\+$"
```

but it doesn't print anything.

That being said, when I run:

```
cat /usr/dict/words | grep -v [A-Zbcdefghijlkpqrtuvwxyz]
```

I get the right output. I'm really confused. What's going on?

Comment: You want them to match *only* those of your name?

Comment: Your example works for me on both os x 10.6 and centos

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are not looking in `/usr/share/dict/words`, I assume you are not on linux.  Given that `+` is a non-standard extension to `grep`, I would guess that the `grep` you are using does not recognize `+`.  Try:

```
 grep '^[mason][mason]*$' /usr/dict/words
```

or

```
grep -E '^[mason]+$' /usr/dict/words
```

Comment: Or just `'^[mason]*$'` - there probably aren't any blank lines in that file.

Comment: None of those suggestions work either, unfortunately. I was running it on a mac, but I just tried all of these things on Linux delhi 3.2.0-35-generic and it didn't work there either